# how to implement attribute base access control in python based web application?

Tags: python, django, rest, xacml, abac

i have a web application written in python(django REST framework) , now i want to implement attribute based access control(ABAC) on my web application for authorization , how can i implement ABAC policies on this application (can i use XACML policies(how to implement xacml on python web app ) or is there any other way to write ABAC policies on python and  how to implement on my web application )
can i use py-ABAC and how to use it ?

```
import vakt
from vakt.rules import Eq, Any, StartsWith, And, Greater, Less

policy = vakt.Policy(
    123456,
    actions=[Eq('fork'), Eq('clone')],
    resources=[StartsWith('repos/Google', ci=True)],
    subjects=[{'name': Any(), 'stars': And(Greater(50), Less(999))}],
    effect=vakt.ALLOW_ACCESS,
    context={'referer': Eq('https://github.com')},
    description="""
    Allow to fork or clone any Google repository for
    users that have > 50 and < 999 stars and came from Github
    """
)
storage = vakt.MemoryStorage()
storage.add(policy)
guard = vakt.Guard(storage, vakt.RulesChecker())

inq = vakt.Inquiry(action='fork',
                   resource='repos/google/tensorflow',
                   subject={'name': 'larry', 'stars': 80},
                   context={'referer': 'https://github.com'})

assert guard.is_allowed(inq)
Or if you prefer Amazon IAM Policies style:

import vakt
from vakt.rules import CIDR

policy = vakt.Policy(
    123457,
    effect=vakt.ALLOW_ACCESS,
    subjects=[r'<[a-zA-Z]+ M[a-z]+>'],
    resources=['library:books:<.+>', 'office:magazines:<.+>'],
    actions=['<read|get>'],
    context={
        'ip': CIDR('192.168.0.0/24'),
    },
    description="""
    Allow all readers of the book library whose surnames start with M get and read any book or magazine,
    but only when they connect from local library's computer
    """,
)
storage = vakt.MemoryStorage()
storage.add(policy)
guard = vakt.Guard(storage, vakt.RegexChecker())

inq = vakt.Inquiry(action='read',
                   resource='library:books:Hobbit',
                   subject='Jim Morrison',
                   context={'ip': '192.168.0.220'})

assert guard.is_allowed(inq)

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@agamgupta1988/xacml-with-wso2-identity-server-bbd9f5c57dad

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with Py-ABAC, but typically XACML is written in XACML, an XML based language, or using a GUI or language that is compiled into XACML, like ALFA.

Then your Python web app will call the Policy Decision Point (PDP) using REST or SOAP, preferably REST. You could use an HTTP library like requests.

Example JSON:

```
{"Request":{"AccessSubject":
{"Attribute":
[ {"AttributeId":"user.name","Value":"alice"} ]
},
"Resource":
{"Attribute":
[ {"AttributeId":"resource.objectType","Value":"insurance claim"} ]
},
"Action":
{"Attribute":
[ {"AttributeId":"action-id","Value":"view"}]
}
}
}
```

Did I mention that it's not exactly advisable (by me at least) to make your own authorization engine (PDP)? There are products that have accomplished externalizing authorization out there...

Use an open source product, like WSO2 or AuthzForce, or buy a product like Axiomatics (full disclosure: I used to work here).

For an entire list of XACML implementations, you can check this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML#XACML_Implementations) on Wikipedia.